# Oracle SQL regarding subquery condition

Tags: sql, oracle, match, top-n

I got a question about Oracle SQL using the subquery.

With a table as shown below

[image]

the question is.

> "Write a query that will display the customer(s) that referred maximum number of customers."

You can see a customer with max number of reference when you execute this code,

```
SELECT cust_referred, COUNT(*) 
FROM customer
WHERE cust_referred IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY cust_referred;
```

I think I need to match cust_num(previous table) to cust_referred with the maximum number of reference, which is 1003 with 3.

Comment: have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: By mistake, we can't see talbe that I uploaded..
I tried
SELECT cust_num, cust_fname, cust_lname FROM customer
GROUP BY cust_num, cust_fname, cust_lname
HAVING cust_num = (
SELECT cust_referred FROM
  (SELECT cust_referred, COUNT(*) FROM customer
  WHERE cust_referred IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY cust_referred)
WHERE COUNT(*) = MAX(COUNT(*))
);

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: Sounds like you want to use analytic functions to find the max number of referred customers and then use that to filter the rows (ie. `where max_num_referred_cust = num_referred_cust`)

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your problem correctly, I think this is what you are looking for

`select 
    cust_num, 
    count(cust_refferred) 
from 
   customer
where cust_referred IS NOT NULL
group by cust_num
order by 2 desc`

Comment: I think you are saying that I can pick the first or last row after ordering. However I can't pick just one if there are more than one maximum number..

Answer (score 0):

`cust_referred` is the Customer who did the referring. So the base query you want is

```
SELECT cust_referred
       , COUNT(*) as referrals
FROM customer
WHERE cust_referred IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY cust_referred
;
```

Now it becomes a top-n question.

> "I can't pick just one if there are more than one maximum number.."

In Oracle 12c there is the marvelous FETCH clause which makes this simple:

```
SELECT cust_referred
       , COUNT(*) as referrals
FROM customer
WHERE cust_referred IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY cust_referred
order by 2 desc
fetch first 1 rows with ties;
```

This (dodgy English grammar but legit Oracle 12c) will return the `cust_refered` with the highest number of referrals, or all of them if there is a tie.

In earlier Oracle versions there are several different implementations but they are all clunkier. For instance:

```
with cte as (  
    SELECT cust_referred
           , COUNT(*) as referrals
    FROM customer
    WHERE cust_referred IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY cust_referred
)
select *
from cte
where cte.referrals = ( select max(referrals) from cte)
/
```